# Como hago para que no me elimine todos los registros mediante este procedimiento de almacenado?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure

Al ejecutar el siguiente procedimiento almacenado se eliminan todos los registros de la tabla, y no comprendo por qué está ocurriendo eso:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE EliminarInstructor(
    in id_instructor INT
)
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM instructor WHERE id_Instructor = id_instructor;
END $$
```

Comment: Cristian, he editado tu pregunta para dar una breve explicación del problema (las preguntas con solo código suelen considerarse de baja calidad porque no explican el problema, aunque en este caso era muy evidente, es mejor dar la explicación, y también para dar formato correcto al código. Te sugiero que hagas clic en "Editar", para ver tu mismo cómo se hace. Bienvenido a StackOverflow, haz el [tour] para aprender sobre como funciona el sitio. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

No utilices como nombre del parámetro de entrada el mismo nombre del campo, pues se crea ambigüedad entre los nombres. En realidad, tu query está comparando siempre que el parámetro de entrada sea igual a si mismo, condición que van a cumplir todas las filas de la tabla.

Podrías resolverlo calificando los nombres, pero es muy sencillo y más fácil de comprender, como te he dicho, evitar la colisión entre los nombres:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EliminarInstructor(
    in pIdInstructor INT
)
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM instructor WHERE id_Instructor = pIdInstructor;
END
```

Como ya te había dicho, puedes calificar el nombre, así:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EliminarInstructor(
    in Id_Instructor INT
)
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM instructor WHERE instructor.id_Instructor = Id_Instructor;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

eso para porque la condición que estas comparando en el "where" siempre que cumple ya que estas comparando el campo con sigo mismo. Como todos los campos cumplen esa condición todos son borrados.